# Storm UI to display topology after killed

Tags: apache-storm

Is there a configuration parameter in storm so that a topology will still be displayed after it is killed ?

Thank you

Comment: Why? So you can view the logs? Couldn't you just deactivate it instead of killing it?

Comment: I am using some one else program which kill the topology based on some logic. I only have control on storm settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no configuration parameter for this. After a Storm topology is killed, it is removed from the Storm UI.  According to Storm's documentation, the Storm UI is only for monitoring "running topologies." See the bottom of the page at https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Running-topologies-on-a-production-cluster.html